# AngularJS TypeScript Service Error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-services

I'm getting this error trying to add a service to a module.  Can someone help point out what's wrong?

Angular 1.5.11 and TypeScript 2.2.2

```
ERROR in ./source/mainModule.ts
(185,33): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof AwesomeService ' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'Injectable<Function>'.
Type 'typeof AwesomeService ' is not assignable to type '(string | Function)[]'.
Property 'push' is missing in type 'typeof AwesomeService '.
```

Here is where I'm trying to add the service

```
export default angular.module('iris.service', [])
    /* This line throws the error --> */.service('awesomeService', AwesomeService);
```

In a separate file, here is how I'm creating the service

```
export class AwesomeService extends OtherClass {

    private static $inject = ['configService'];

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

### update:

I see that if I change AwesomeService to a function and export that, it works fine.  Is there any way I can use a class for a Service?  It looks like @types/angular specifies that the second argument to angular.module.service should be either a string or a function.

Comment: What about if you capitalise 'AwesomeService' like this:
`export default angular.module('iris.service', []).service('AwesomeService', AwesomeService);`

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  That can be any arbitrary name.

Comment: :) okay, I might have a think a little later

Comment: @Spencer yeah, the only advantage to using the same casing for the registered name and the registered value is that you can write `.module('iris.service', []).service({ AwesomeService })` which is a convenient shorthand especially if you use certain registration patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly what you want, you simply need to write less code.

The type declaration in `@types/angular` includes the following

```
declare global {
    interface Function {
        $inject?: ReadonlyArray<string>;
    }
}
```

This augments the declaration of the `Function` type.
Adding an optional property, `$inject`, to allow for clean, readable AngularJS DI annotations to be added to classes and functions in a type safe and declarative manner without the need for unsightly type assertions.

Note that all classes and functions are in fact functions.

The problem with your class is that, while the `Function` type augmentation above states that `$inject` is optional, it does *not* state that when it *is* specified, that it may be `private`.

In fact, it is very much not private, semantically, as it is read by the AngularJS framework and potentially other tools as well.

To resolve the issue simply write

```
export class AwesomeService extends OtherClass {

    static $inject = ['configService']; // no private here.

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The more detailed answer is that two types are considered structurally incompatible if one declares a private member (to do this it needs to be a class) with the same name as a public member in the other (all interface members are public).

Unfortunately, the error is a bit cryptic. The `private $inject` declaration causes the type checker to immediately remove the overload of `service` which takes a value of type `Function`. It then tries the overload of `service` which takes a value of type `Array` and fails.

Comment: Amazing.  I guess I was thinking of the transpiled JavaScript where public/private both turn into the same `AwesomeService.$inject`.  Thanks for helping me remember that TypeScript is smarter!

Comment: Glad to help :)